# Search Through A DataTable LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to return a list of data rows where a filed in a datatable matches some criteria. Here is what I have

```
'Dim returnedList = myDatatable.Where(Function(x) x.Item("TagergetField").ToString = "TheCriteria").ToList()
```

My Where clause isnt correct and I am not sure how to return a filtered datatable with only the records that match my criteria. I want to return a datatable object not a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x("TagergetField").ToString = "TheCriteria").ToList()
```

this will return a `List(Of DataRow)`

You could achieve the same result without resorting to Linq

```
Dim rows = dataTable.Select("TargetField = 'TheCriteria'").ToList()
```

Note how the last one is more readable and considerably more performant (Just tested)

**EDIT**

To get a datatable you could use the DataSetExtension namespace method [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim dataTable1 = rows.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: Will the second one return a datatable?

Comment: Neither the first one returns a datatable. They both return a List(Of DataRow)

Comment: However, you could call the CopyToDataTable method to get it